# Visual Studio 2015:How to create for a solution its own git repo when one if its projects is already in its own git repo

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I have developed a library stored in a local git repo, VSO (Visual Studio Online) and codeplex (https://acorelib.codeplex.com/). All works fine.

I then made a new solution and added the project ACoreLib. I can now not figure out how to create a Git repo for the new solution. In the File menu, there is no "Add to source control". Team Explorer links automatically to the ACoreLib repo. VS seems to think that the new solution belongs to the ACoreLib repo.

I have only limited knowledge of Git. I would appreciate to solve my problem from within Visual Studio 2015 as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some days of trying, I found the following solution of my problem:

1) Unload the project(s) which is/are already in its/their own Git repo(s).

2) Now *Add to Source Control* appears in the File menu. Execute it

3) Reload the unloaded project(s)

Answer (score 0):

To create a solution for a new git repo, you can use below steps:

File -> New -> project -> select the type of project you wan to add -> select an empty folder which’s parent is not a git repo for **Location** -> choose **Create new Git repository** -> ok.

Now a new local git repo is created, if you also want the new create repo connected with VSO or CodePlex, you can follow these steps: Team explorer -> Sync -> click Publish Git Repo for VSO or other remote repo (such as CodePlex).

[image]

Comment: The problem is that I have an existing project and can therefore not make a new one, as you suggest. Even if I make a new project, VS still does not show 'Add to Source Control' in the file menu. See my answer how I solved the problem.